# How do I download an image using selenium python?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium to go through a webpage and I want to download/save all images I find and save them to a specific directory I define, how would I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `urllib.requests.urlretrieve` which did what I wanted.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import os
import urllib.requests

images = find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'img')
for image in images:
    src = image.get_attribute('src')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, os.path.join("C:\\Users\\Name\\Desktop\\images", "my_image" + ".jpg"))
```

One slight drawback, that wasn't an issue for me but might be for someone reading this is that I had to specify what file type to save the image as, if I didn't put `".jpg"` it saved the file as a weird text file.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase solution for that (`pip install seleniumbase` and run with `python` / `pytest`). First it goes to the site. Then it finds all unique images (`img[src]`), downloads all the ones that are `.png`, `.jpg`, and `.jpeg` into the `./downloaded_files/` folder, verifies they are all there, and prints out the file paths.

```py
import os
from seleniumbase import BaseCase
BaseCase.main(__name__, __file__)

class DownloadImages(BaseCase):
    def test_download_images_directly(self):
        self.open("seleniumbase.io/examples/chart_maker/ReadMe")
        img_elements_with_src = self.find_elements("img[src]")
        unique_src_values = []
        for img in img_elements_with_src:
            src = img.get_attribute("src")
            if src not in unique_src_values:
                unique_src_values.append(src)
        print()
        for src in unique_src_values:
            if src.split(".")[-1] not in ["png", "jpg", "jpeg"]:
                continue
            self.download_file(src, "./downloaded_files/")
            filename = src.split("/")[-1]
            self.assert_downloaded_file(filename)
            folder = "downloaded_files"
            file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
            print(file_path)
```

Running that today produces the following printed output for that page:

```
downloaded_files/logo3c.png
downloaded_files/logo6.png
downloaded_files/sample_pie_chart.png
downloaded_files/sample_column_chart.png
downloaded_files/sample_bar_chart.png
downloaded_files/sample_line_chart.png
downloaded_files/sample_area_chart.png
downloaded_files/multi_series_chart.png
```

(Source: [SeleniumBase/examples/test_download_images.py](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/examples/test_download_images.py) on GitHub)

Also note that the `./downloaded_files/` folder is special in SeleniumBase: Certain methods such as `self.assert_downloaded_file(file)` will specifically look in that folder.

Comment: Thanks for this. I gave it a go but struggled to integrate it with my current isntance of selenium webdriver that was already running through the pages. In the end I found ```urllib.requests.urlretrieve``` that worked well